# how to set array list values retrieved from MySQL into text box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist, textbox

I am beginner to programming, if there is any big mistakes in my code please be kind.

Below is my function, i need to set the Arraylist values retrieved from the java page to texbox, below is the function that i tried. when i tried to alert the entire list, it is working but when i try "status.get(i)" it is not working. My arraylist size is "20".

My ArrayList Returned from java page (mysql):-

```
[west, 9.994042, 76.356653, 9.994195, 76.357181, north, 9.994182, 76.357176, 9.994702, 76.357299, south, 9.993839, 76.357213, 9.994127, 76.357329, east, 9.994127, 76.357329, 9.994261, 76.357924]
```

below is my code:-

```
function Locstatus(){
    <%
    String check="zone";
    dbLayer dbstatus=new dbLayer();
    ArrayList<String> status=dbstatus.LocStatus(check);
    int size= status.size();

    %>      
                var status = '<%= status %>'.slice(1, -1).split(',');

        alert(status);
        document.getElementById('sww_lat').value=status[0];
        document.getElementById('sww_lon').value=status[2];

        document.getElementById('new_lat').value=status[3];
        document.getElementById('new_lon').value=status[4];

        document.getElementById('nen_lat').value=status[3];
        document.getElementById('nen_lon').value=status[2];

        document.getElementById('sws_lat').value=status[4];
        document.getElementById('sws_lon').value=status[6];

        document.getElementById('nes_lat').value=status[7];
        document.getElementById('nes_lon').value=status[8];

        document.getElementById('nee_lat').value=status[9];
        document.getElementById('nee_lon').value=status[10];
}
```

I need to set most the the values retrieved from the ArrayList to respective textbox. I am not sure the forloop is needed for my case or not, please correct my program. any piece of code is appreciated & Thanks in advance

Comment: I have been sitting with this for 4 hours, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP i tired by replacing 'i' with (0,1,2,3) but not working :(

Comment: Can you show the output you get when you do `alert(status);`

Comment: @Jimmy Jutt [west, 9.994042, 76.356653, 9.994195, 76.357181, north, 9.994182, 76.357176, 9.994702, 76.357299, south, 9.993839, 76.357213, 9.994127, 76.357329, east, 9.994127, 76.357329, 9.994261, 76.357924]

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP i have updated my program, now the other functions in the page is working but "status.get(0)" is not working :(

Comment: even alert(status.get(0)); is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be that that `status` is just a string, not a list.

Try this:

```
var status = '<%= status %>'.slice(1, -1).split(',');

document.getElementById('sww_lat').value = status[0];
```

This should work if `<%= status %>` actually gives the array as a String, like you said it does if you use it in `alert();`.

Comment: I tried:-  var status = <%= status %>.slice(1, -1).split(',');
   alert(status[0]);
   document.getElementById('sww_lat').value=status[0];

Comment: No result for  alert(status); also

Comment: Where do i have to put single quto? '<%= status %>' ? like this:- document.getElementById('sww_lon').value='<%= status.get(1) %>'; ?

Comment: did it. single quto didnt make change in the output

Comment: i dont know exactly, now it seems to be like even alert('<%= status %>'); The java code is woking fine:-      System.out.println("Size:"+size); is not working :( This part consumed my half day

Comment: @MohamedAshref It is likely that the problem is with with java code, because the js code is working fine. It could be that the `ArrayList` is not being populated. You can test the js code by hard-coding an ArrayList and putting a few values in it, and then passing that to the js.

Comment: @Jummy Jutt i am getting the ArraList as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MohamedAshref Ok, before the `var status = ....` line, can you put `alert('test');`, and confirm that you get an alert.

Comment: alert('test'); is working. But  alert(<%= status %>); is not working. But after i tried alert('test'), now the new var status is working. I dont know what is the reason behind this. Thank you verymuch :)

Comment: Maybe the system restart between yesterday & today have also helped!